# Seeing if something is in an array or making a new entry in the array

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to get the following array to check to see if the current user is already in the list of users or if I need to make a new entry in the array, but I am not sure how to do this dynamically.

Here is my current code. I have a query above this that is working fine. I posted the `bind_result` so you all could see the variables I assigned.

How can I do this?

```
$stmt->bind_result($ordering, $userid, $username, $playername);
$users = array();
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    $users = array(
     $user = array('name' => $username, 'players' => array($playername))

     );
}
print_r($users);
```

Answer (score 1):

Is something like that what you need?

```
$users = array();
$user[] = array('name' => "1", 'players' => "players");
$user[] = array('name' => "2", 'players' => "players");
$user[] = array('name' => "3", 'players' => "players");
$user[] = array('name' => "1", 'players' => "players"); // this won't be included
$user[] = array('name' => "4", 'players' => "players");
$user[] = array('name' => "5", 'players' => "players");

foreach ($user as $u) {
    if(!in_array($u, $users)) $users[] = $u;
}

print_r($users);
```

If so, you just need to change these lines

```
$users = array(
     $user = array('name' => $username, 'players' => array($playername))
);
```

to these

```
$user = array('name' => $username, 'players' => array($playername));
if(!in_array($user, $users)) $users[] = $user;
```

Then your final code would be

```
$stmt->bind_result($ordering, $userid, $username, $playername);
$users = array();
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    $user = array('name' => $username, 'players' => array($playername));
    if(!in_array($user, $users)) $users[] = $user;
}
print_r($users);
```

## Edit

If you want to check only the `name` key, change the while to this:

```
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    $user = array('name' => $username, 'players' => array($playername));
    foreach ($users as $uname) if ($uname['name'] == $u['name']) continue 2;
    $users[] = $user;
}
```

That's not the best way to do that, in terms of performance.

Comment: That displays like this..`Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => pfar54 [players] => Array ( ) ) [1] => Array ( [name] => pfar54 [players] => Array ( [0] => Eddie Lacey ) ) )`

Comment: Your update code shows like this... `Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => pfar54 [players] => Array ( [0] => Tom Brady ) ) [1] => Array ( [name] => ahaas18 [players] => Array ( [0] => ) ) [2] => Array ( [name] => Big Daddy [players] => Array ( [0] => ) ) [3] => Array ( [name] => pfar54 [players] => Array ( [0] => ) ) [4] => Array ( [name] => Ja-queline [players] => Array ( [0] => ) ) [5] => Array ( [name] => jwhittaker [players] => Array ( [0] => ) ) [6] => Array ( [name] => Big Daddy [players] => Array ( [0] => Aaron Rodgers ) ) [7] => Array ( [name] =>` With a little bit more to it, it repeats

Comment: @Paul Each `$user` you posted is different, they just have the same `name`. If that is what you really mean by the same, just having the same name, see my edit.